# How to use Swift to read the AXRoleDescription and accessibility Hierarchy?

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to read an Application that uses Accessibility on the macOS.  I am going to run a Swift application that will not down the changes in the other application.  I am trying to only use Swift

I do not want to user AppleScript it takes up to much memory.  I do not want to use Python to select coordinates and read the raw text since the app moves its window

if the text label says "Hello" I want to be able to read "Hello"

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: there is currently no code since I am not able to find a way to do it in swift or Objective-C.  I only can use UI scripting with AppleScript.  That takes a lot of memory on a background process.